# Why don't variables work for saving youtube-dl archive files?

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-dl

When saving files from  `Youtube playlists` , I'm about to use variables such as `%(playlist_title)s`  to create save directories for the videos.

However, I don't understand why I can't use the same variable to save an archive file.

Like so:

`Videos\Online Videos\Comics Explained\%(playlist_title)s\%(playlist_title)s Archive.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the output template parameters (e.g. the video description) are calculated from the result of the extraction. When I wrote the `--download-archive` code, the main design goal was to be able to skip the time-consuming extraction whenever possible.

In this case, `playlist_title` is one of the few fields that could be available, but adding template parameter substitution would likely be quite tricky in the general case. Remember that [all features start at -100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/).

However, the download archive is small enough that it should be perfectly fine to use just one common archive for all playlists. Simply pass in

```
--download-archive "Videos/Online Videos/Comics Explained/archive.txt"
```